# iOS 11 MDM: managed app configuration doesn't work

Tags: swift, ios11, enterprise, mdm, managed

```
let serverConfig = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed") print("serverConfig count:
\(String(describing: serverConfig?.count))")
```

Above code always returning nil for iOS 11.

I want transfer few data to managed application using MDM portal via managed configuration as per the apple developer [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html) they didn't update anything in to it. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.Please help me out with this.

Comment: Hello Tejas,

Are you getting answer of it ?

Please help me for same

Comment: maybe this does help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261939