# read Microsoft Intune app configuration properties from cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, nsuserdefaults, mdm, intune

app configuration properties can be deployed to an iOS app with the Microsoft Intune app configuration policies. These properties are configured in plist format and deployed like explained in the docs 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/IntuneDocs/blob/master/intune/app-configuration-policies-use-ios.md

it seems like this properties can be read by the Intune iOS SDK as "MDM app config" like explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-ios#enable-targeted-configuration-appmam-app-config-for-your-ios-applications
(i could not try this)

how does Intune deploy these plist settings? Does it create an plist file in the apps private directory? If yes, how is this file called?

If not, how can i access this properties from cordova without the intune sdk? I could not find any hints in the SDKs source code on how they are stored / received.

Comment: i already tried reading the NSUserDefaults settings after the policie is applied to the device (using the cordova-plugin-nativestorage plugin) - but i could not find the keys in this storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is the right storage, by using the `cordova-plugin-emm-app-config` plugin i figured out the values coming from an MDM server are stored in the `com.apple.configuration.managed` dictionary key within the NSUserDefaults.

so reading the MDM app config like this works fine for Intune:

`NSDictionary *appConfig = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:kConfigurationKey];`